# How does the distribution of the mass of an object affect its angular velocity?

Tags: angular-velocity

I was wondering if someone could explain to me how the distribution of mass affects angular momentum. I have tried to do some research but had no luck anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The distribution of mass affects the angular momentum through the **moment of inertia** (usually $I$).

The angular momentum is given by: 
$\vec L = I \vec \omega $
where $\vec \omega$ is the angular velocity.

Let's assume we're talking about a rigid body spinning around a single axis. If the mass is concentrated near the axis, then it has a relatively low moment of inertia. The further away the mass is from the axis, the higher the moment of inertia.

For a point mass $m$ a distance $r$ away from the axis of rotation, the moment of inertia is $I=mr^2$. 
Here's the [moment of inertia for some common objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_moments_of_inertia):

A solid sphere: $I=\frac{2}{5}mr^2$

A hollow sphere: $I=\frac{2}{3}mr^2$

The coefficient in front comes from the shape of the mass. For a hollow sphere, the mass is further from the axis of rotation, so it has a higher $I$ for the same $m$.

A really great example is a figure skater. The start out a spin slowly with their arms out and then pull them in to lower their moment of inertia (and by conservation of angular momentum) increase their angular velocity. [description here](http://www.bsharp.org/physics/spins)

Wikipedia: [Moment of inertia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_of_inertia)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [Wikipedia article on moment of inertia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_of_inertia) as a starting point. In particular, the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_of_inertia#Definition) section includes an explanation of how mass distributions come into play:

> For a simple pendulum, this definition yields a formula for the moment of inertia $I$ in terms of the mass $m$ of the pendulum and its distance $r$ from the pivot point as,
>   \begin{equation}
> I = m r^2 .
> \end{equation}
>   Thus, moment of inertia of the pendulum depends on both the mass $m$ of a body and its geometry, or shape, as defined by the distance $r$ to the axis of rotation.
>
> This simple formula generalizes to define moment of inertia for an arbitrarily shaped body as the sum of all the elemental point masses $\mathrm{d}m$ each multiplied by the square of its perpendicular distance $r$ to an axis $k$. An arbitrary object's moment of inertia thus depends on the spatial distribution of its mass.